# ASP.net web api

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-web-api

I've been reading up about MVC 4 and was interested in the web API feature. 
In what scenarios would it be advantageous to use web api over a WCF Http service?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Web API provides far more access to all aspects of the HTTP interaction.  It was designed from the ground up around the HTTP spec.  WCF is fine if you are just using HTTP to get through the firewall.  If you really want to use HTTP as an application protocol, you will find Web API much easier.